# Differentiate under integral sign for iterated integral?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

This is a bit of a trivial question, but as I don't know the answer immediately I thought I'd just ask.

Given the integral $\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t} f(x,x') dx dx'$, what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t} f(x,x') dx dx'$? It looks a bit like differentiating under the integral sign, but I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: 'as I don't know the answer immediately I thought I'd just ask" ... is this a polite way of saying you've thought about it a bit and can't remember how to do it? (and FWIW it is *not* like differentiating under the integral sign; moreover, without some conditions on $f$ it's not clear to me that you can say anything precise)

Comment: Also, at the risk of sounding like a grump, did you check the site's FAQ first? http://mathoverflow.net/faq

Comment: For `$f$` continuous, just draw the darn square and ask yourself what the difference is between integrating over `$[0,t]^2$` and over `$[0,t+{\rm d}t]^2$`.

Answer (score 5):

As usual when differentiating something with respect to a variable that appears twice.  The chain rule for partial derivatives.

For example, consider function $z = f(u,v)$.  Suppose we want $(d/dt)f(t,t)$.  Let $u=v=t$ and use
 $dz/dt = (\partial z/\partial u)(du/dt) + (\partial z/\partial v)(dv/dt)$.

Thus…
$$
  \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t\int_0^t f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = 
  \int_0^t f(t,y)\,dy + \int_0^t f(x,t)\,dx
$$

By the way, why did you write $\partial/\partial t$ to differentiate a function of the single variable $t$?  It's not wrong, just confusing to students.